# How to cache data into Pyspark before using multiple sql.write functions properly

Tags: python, apache-spark, caching, pyspark

I'm new to pyspark, and I'm trying to create a Insert Update component.

Basically I got a dataframe, "df", with a column named "action", where I can filter the actions between "insert" and "update". The code looks something like that:

```
df_to_insert = df.filter(df.action == 1)
df_to_upsert = df.filter(df.action == 2)
```

What I'm trying to do is chaching the dataframe df, this way I can use a count operation to see if there is any row to update or to insert in a faster way:

```
cached_dataframe = df.cache()
df_to_insert = df.filter(df.action == 1)
df_to_update = df.filter(df.action == 2)

if df_to_insert.count() != 0:
    #insert rows

if df_to_update.count() != 0:
    #update rows
```

As you should know, the first count is quite slow, once the pyspark applies all the transformations required, but the second one is much faster, since I cached the dataframe df.

After chaching the data and diving it between insert and update I just need to drop the "action" column, then I'm using the io.github.spark_redshift_community.spark.redshift connector to perform a write function into a redshift database. The code looks like this:

```
df_to_insert.write.format("io.github.spark_redshift_community.spark.redshift").options(
            url=f"jdbc:redshift://{HOST_REDSHIFT}:{PORT_REDSHIFT}/{DATABASE_REDSHIFT}",   
            user=USER_REDSHIFT,
            password=PASSWORD_REDSHIFT,
            tempdir= f"s3a://{S3_BUCKET}/test_folder",
            dbtable=table,
            forward_spark_s3_credentials="true",
            fetchsize="100000") \
        .mode("append").save()
```

But performing the insert with cached data to a database is taking to long.

What is the best approach here?
Should I cache the data in this case?
If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: there are multiple factors which are not clear here. For example: which dataframe are you trying to write? do you apply any other transformations before writing? which writer are you using?
You should check your SparkUI to see if your write job uses cached data

Comment: if you're going to use `df_to_insert` and `df_to_update` for the write, you should `cache()` them when required

Comment: Hello @HoangNguyen!
I edited the question so you can better undertand the situation. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @samkart but why chaching it is increasing the time needed to perform the insert?